# Show Array of Images

Tags: php, html, loops, html-table, nested

I'm trying to display image in 5 by 3 table.

I'm able to display the images if all empty(blank.png).

Here is the code

```
<?PHP

$ds ='\image';
$imagefile = array("EX_W1_01.png", "EX_W1_02.png", "EX_W2_01.png","EX_W3_01.png");
echo "<pre>"; print_r($imagefile);
$file = 'blank.png';
$d = $ds.$file;

echo "<table border = 1 width=\"540px\" cellspacing=\"0px\" cellpadding=\"0px\">";
for($row=1;$row<=5;$row++){
   echo "<tr>";

      for($col=1;$col<=3;$col++){

           // echo"<td height=60px>W$row</td>";
           //if()
           echo"<td height=60px>W$row<img border = 1 height = 120 width = 120 src = $d ></td>" .PHP_EOL;

      }
   echo "</tr>";

}
echo "</table>";     
?>
```

I want to display the images base on middle file name array `$imagefile eg W1, W2` and if not in array, I will  display the blank.png.

I was able to get the middle file name by this code, but I cannot display the images in correct row/col.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($imagefile); $i++)  {
    $wd = substr($imagefile[$i], 3, strpos($imagefile[$i], '_'));
}
```

Comment: Are the images listed in the array also under the path `\image`?

Comment: yes same path only different images to display.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

Based on your code add these when you echo the image,

```
$wd = substr($imagefile[$i], 3, strpos($imagefile[$i], '_'));
if($wd == *the increment either row or col*) 
{
   echo"<td height=60px>W$row<img border = 1 height = 120 width = 120 src = $d ></td>" .PHP_EOL;       
}
else
{
   echo"<td height=60px>No image</td>" .PHP_EOL;
}
```

See if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

```
<?php

$ds ='/image';
$imagefile = array("EX_W1_01.png", "EX_W1_02.png", "EX_W2_01.png","EX_W3_01.png");
//echo "<pre>"; print_r($imagefile);
$default = 'blank.png';
?>

<table border = 1 width=\"540px\" cellspacing=\"0px\" cellpadding=\"0px\">
<?php
for($row=1;$row<=5;$row++){
?>
    <tr>
<?php
    for($col=1;$col<=3;$col++){
        // construct the file name
        $filename = 'EX_W' . $row . '_0' . $col . '.png';
        // set the default image file
        $imgPath = $ds . '/' . $default;
        // in case the file name exists in your array with images,
        // set the correct path to the image
        if (in_array($filename, $imagefile)) {
            $imgPath = $ds . '/' . $filename;
        } 
?>
        <td height=60px>
            <img border="1" height="120" width="120" src="<?php echo $imgPath; ?>"/>
        </td>
<?php } ?>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

As you can see I also prefer to "embed" the php code in the HTML. It makes no sense to me outputting HTML code through the PHP engine if it can be parsed as is ;-)

Comment: Hi Havelock, you're right it is working as it is, my only issue is since the last 2 digits are randomize from table, I will not be able to get the correct filename. This the reason I need to parse and get the middle file name. Thanks again for helping